# Whats the correct way to do this variable overwriting?

Tags: java, parameters, variable-assignment

When overwriting an existing variable, `someThing` of type `Thing` below in a method, what is the correct way to do this?

```
doSomething(someThing);

void doSomething(Thing thing){
    //...
    thing = new Thing(...); // receives warning in Eclipse
}
```

or

```
someThing = doSomething(someThing);

Thing doSomething(Thing thing){
    //...
    return new Thing(...);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first sample doesn't change the variable `someThing` in the caller. The assignment is only visible in the `doSomething` method.

The second sample does change `someThing` in the caller.

So if you want to change `someThing` in the caller, option 2 is viable, while option 1 is not.

See [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) for why this works that way.

Assuming the following code, and a `Thing` that has a print method and a String member.

```
void foo() {
  Thing one = new Thing("hello");  // 1
  bar(one);
  one.print();                   // 5
}

void bar(Thing two) {            // 2
  two = new Thing("bye");        // 3
}                                // 4
```

The assignment at  point `1` first creates a new Thing object:

```
                       Thing{data="hello"}
```

Then stores a reference to that in `one`:

```
one *----- refs --------v
                       Thing{data="hello"}
```

When you enter `bar` at point `2`, a new reference to the same object is created:

```
one *----- refs --------v
                       Thing{data="hello"}
two *----- refs --------^
```

Then line `3` does the same thing as line `1`, i.e. create a new `Thing` object:

```
one *----- refs --------v
                       Thing{data="hello"}
two *----- refs --------^

                       Thing{data="bye"}
```

then stores a reference to that new object in `two`:

```
one *----- refs --------v
                       Thing{data="hello"}

two *----- refs --------v
                       Thing{data="bye"}
```

Notice that only `two` is modified. The assignment changes what `two` refers to.

When you return from `bar`, at line `4`, `two` goes out of scope, the "bye" Thing no longer has anything referencing it (and will eventually be garbage collected).

```
one *----- refs --------v
                       Thing{data="hello"}

                       Thing{data="bye"} // dead, will be collected
```

So at point `5`, as you can see, `hello` will be printed - nothing ever changed the object that `one` refers to.

Comment: Oooh... I might have screwed up here

Comment: _why_ is this? Is it because I am overwriting the also the reference to `someThing` in the first case?